# What is the difference between @RepositoryRestController and the @Repository annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I want to know what exactly the difference between using the annotation `@RepositoryRestController` and `@Repository` because I've tried them both and I find absolutely no difference!

I tried the following:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface MovieRepository extends JpaRepository<Movie, Short> { 
}
```

and

```
@Repository
public interface MovieRepository extends JpaRepository<Movie, Short> { 
}
```

so when I try : **/movies** in both methods I get the same results.

And if I use `@RepositoryRestController` should I use `@RepositoryRestController`, or I can use `@RestController`, and is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### `@Repository`

[`@Repository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html) is a stereotype interface for defining a *repository* originally defined by Domain-Driven Design (Evans, 2003) as *"a mechanism for encapsulating storage, retrieval, and search behavior which emulates a collection of objects"*.

This annotation also serves as a specialization of [`@Component`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html), allowing for implementation classes to be autodetected through classpath scanning.

### `@RepositoryRestResource`

[`@RepositoryRestResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/annotation/RepositoryRestResource.html) tells [Spring Data REST](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/) to expose your repository as REST endpoints. Check the [relevant](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.collection-resource) part of the documentation.

---

If you want to write a custom handler for a specific resource taking advantage of Spring Data REST’s settings, message converters, exception handling and more, you can use [`@RepositoryRestController`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryRestController.html) (instead of the standard Spring MVC [`@Controller`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.html) or [`@RestController`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) annotations). See the [relevant](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers) part of the documentation.

Comment: Where in the Javadoc for `@Repository` do you find any hint about Spring Data or interfaces? On the contrary, that annotation has nothing to do with Spring Data and doesn't have any effect on Spring Data interfaces. From the Javadoc: `As of Spring 2.5, this annotation also serves as a specialization of @Component`

Answer (score 4):

The reason why it works in your case with or without the annotations, is because if you use Spring Boot together with Spring Data REST, in that case an auto configuration is activated, which automatically exposes all Spring Data interfaces as REST resource. You can find the source code for this configuration [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration.java), and more about the possibilities to customize it in the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-exposing-spring-data-repositories-rest-endpoint).

Answer (score 3):

**`@Repository:`**

Spring @Repository annotation denotes that the class provide mechanism for crud operations.

You can find more information [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html).

**`@RepositoryRestResource:`**

This annotation gives RestController functionality to the repository. This means you can access your Repository directly. You can read further about this [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/annotation/RepositoryRestResource.html).